# Activiti BPM: How can I get list of deleted process instance (task)

Tags: task, activiti, business-process-management

How can I get list of deleted process instances (tasks). One way is to get the information for method `getDeletedReason`. However, do you have any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sql query should give you all non completed historic instances without an active execution:

```
select h.proc_inst_id_ from act_hi_procinst h 
left join act_ru_execution x on x.proc_inst_id_ = h.proc_inst_id_ 
where h.end_act_id_ is null and x.proc_inst_id_ is null
```